# Distance matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix

I have to create a distance matrix using R. My data is in an Excel file which contains 300 rows and 10 columns. I have to create distance matrix based on the values of 9th column. For example

```
   s s s s s
s  1
s  2 2
s  3 3 4
s  4 4 7 3
s  5 5 8 2 8
```

How to create this type of matrix?

Comment: Do you know how to get the data out of excel into R? You're really asking two questions here.

Answer (score 8):

Easiest option I know, is to save your Excel sheet containing the data as a CSV file. Make sure that only the first row and column of the sheet contain any sample or variable names.

Then read into R using:

```
dat <- read.csv("path/to/my/file.csv")
```

and then use `dist()` on the 9th column to compute the dissimilarity matrix

```
dij <- dist(dat[, 9])
```

If you want something other than the Euclidean distance, see the options in `?dist` and if those don't suit, try the `daisy()` function in recommended package **cluster**, or `vegdist()` function in package **[vegan](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/vegan/index.html)** or the **[proxy](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/proxy/index.html)** package.

Comment: @Simpson I tried your code .But I got the error like this.dij <- dist(myfile[, 9])
Error in myfile[, 9] : incorrect number of dimensions

Answer (score 4):

If your numbers are in a vector called z, then `dist(z)` returns a distance matrix of euclidean (`sqrt(dx^2+dy^2)`) values. See `help(dist)` for more info.

Comment: quick and dirty answer is quick and dirty.... Probably longer than what you'd get on r-help: "?dist"