# building matrix out of a vector with the difference of each value

Tags: r, matrix

```
dataset2 <- data.frame(bird=c("A","B","C","D","E","F"), rank=c(1:6))
```

I have this example dataset and now i want to build a 6*6 matrix with the rank difference between each bird. How can i do this?

Comment: Can you show the expected output

Comment: See This http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20038922/vector-to-matrix-of-differences-between-elements or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6923547/distance-matrix-in-r

Comment: @user8333220 Hi, if any answer solves your problem can you click on "accept it" so that other people can see it? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
m <- with(dataset2, outer(rank, rank, '-'))
rownames(m) <- colnames(m) <- dataset2$bird

  # A  B  C  D  E  F
# A 0 -1 -2 -3 -4 -5
# B 1  0 -1 -2 -3 -4
# C 2  1  0 -1 -2 -3
# D 3  2  1  0 -1 -2
# E 4  3  2  1  0 -1
# F 5  4  3  2  1  0
```

You *might* also want to do this afterwards:

```
m[upper.tri(m)] <- 0
tail(m[,-ncol(m)],-1)
```

To get:

```
#  A B C D E
#B 1 0 0 0 0
#C 2 1 0 0 0
#D 3 2 1 0 0
#E 4 3 2 1 0
#F 5 4 3 2 1
```

Comment: ok my problem now is, that i need dataset2$bird is, that i have to run dist() so that i dont have a double result. After doing so my col- and rownames are away. The problem is her now that i erase one column with this function and i get an error. How can i solve that. Sry i am new in R.

Comment: m <- with(d2, dist(rank))
rownames(m) <- colnames(m) <- d2$bird

Comment: @TimoRath do you want a square matrix (n*n) at the end or what?

Comment: yeah because i want to compare two matrixes with the mantel test and so i need the colnames and rownames and a square matrix. I should have said that before

Comment: @TimoRath what if you run this as last line? `m[upper.tri(m)] <- 0`

Comment: @TimoRath OR this `tail(m[,-ncol(m)],-1)`?

Comment: actually i get an error use colnames for less then two dimensions

Comment: @TimoRath If you run my code and this `tail(m[,-ncol(m)],-1)` afterwards, based on your given data here, you should not get any error.

Comment: that doesnt work because my original datas are not sorted like in this example i gave. I have to take dist(). A short cut of my original data is: d2<-data.frame(bird=c("Altea","Apollo","Bolti"), rank=c(18,9,15). I sorted the birds before and i need the differences between the ranks with the birdnames as col and row so that i can compare it with a table in form of a matrix.

Comment: @TimoRath Do this beforehand `dataset2 <- d2[order(d2$rank),]` and run my updated code.

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of the definition of the distance matrix, no?

```
dist(dataset2, method="maximum")
####  
 1        
 2 1      
 3 2 1    
 4 3 2 1  
 5 4 3 2 1
```

With the distinction that it returns positive distance only... maybe it doesn't suits the OP..